# Continuous background-image pattern over several elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background, background-image

I need to make a **continous background pattern over several elements**. 
I can't control the height of the elements or their number.
Here is an example:

```css
p{
  margin:0;
  padding:1.5em;
}
.bg{
  background-image:url('http://enjoycss.com/webshots/hB_1.png');
}
```

```html
<p>some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
```

The effect I am looking for is almost achieved with `background-attachement:fixed;` but I need the background to scroll with the content.
Example:

```css
p{
  margin:0;
  padding:1.5em;
}
.bg{
  background-image:url('http://enjoycss.com/webshots/hB_1.png');
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

```html
<p>some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap them in a `div` and have the background assigned on that one?

Comment: @NicklasNygren no, the content is generated by a WYSIWYG editor and the client can't make a container, he can only change the class of the `p` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Javascript

Using a small amount of JavaScript, you can get the effect you require.

This method gets the current height and adds all the previous heights to give the element its starting background position.

```js
var lastHeight = 0;
$('.bg').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-position', '0 -' + lastHeight + 'px');
  var currentHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  var newPosition = currentHeight + lastHeight;
  lastHeight = lastHeight + currentHeight;
});
```

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em;
}
.bg {
  background-image: url('http://enjoycss.com/webshots/hB_1.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some 
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p class="bg">some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can let the paragraph min-height/line-height in harmony with the background-image size:

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/TbQPryV.png');
  background-size: 1em 1em;
  min-height: 1em;
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(0,0,0,0.3);  
}
```

```html
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
<p>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another<br>some text<br>on several lines<br><br>and another</p>
```

Comment: Good approach but unfortunatly my background pattern is higher than the line height.

Answer (score 0):

I have done with without `background:fixed`. please check and let me know its useful for you or not???

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/68gn57rj/)

If m not get any point of yours then let me know.

Comment: thx for the answer but as I commented, I can't wrap the elements in a container to add the background